# How to read a file device in Linux using Qt?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I'm working on a small Qt5-based GUI, which shall display a data stream from a Linux file device.
For that I choose a joystick input. With `cat /dev/input/js0` it is possible to see the incoming stream on the terminal.

Using C you can read this device file using a loop with a blocking read or handle the device signals. But I don't get this with Qt.

What is the typical approach to interact with device files using Qt?

---

Based on the answer of @rodrigo here a new implementation:

*joystick.h*

```
#ifndef JOYSTICK_H
#define JOYSTICK_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QFile>
#include <QSocketNotifier>

class Joystick
      : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QString fileName = "/dev/input/js0";
    QFile *file;
    QSocketNotifier *notifier;

public:
    explicit Joystick(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~Joystick();

signals:

public slots:
    void handle_readNotification(int socket);
};

#endif // JOYSTICK_H
```

*joystick.cpp*

```
#include "joystick.h"

Joystick::Joystick(QObject *parent)
   : QObject(parent)
{
    file = new QFile();
    file->setFileName(fileName);
    if( !file->exists() ){
        qWarning("file does not exist");
        return;
    }

    if( !file->open(QFile::ReadOnly) ){
        qWarning("can not open file");
        return;
    }

    notifier = new QSocketNotifier( file->handle(),
                                    QSocketNotifier::Read,
                                    this);

    connect( notifier,
             &QSocketNotifier::activated,
             this,
             &Joystick::handle_readNotification );

    if( !notifier->isEnabled() ){
        qInfo("enable notifier");
        notifier->setEnabled(true);
    }
    qInfo("Joystick init ready");
}

void
Joystick::handle_readNotification(int /*socket*/)
{
    static quint64 cnt=0;
    qInfo("cnt: %d",cnt++);

    if( !(file->isOpen()) ){
        qWarning("file closed");
        return;
    }

    char buf[16]; /* tested with different sizes */
    if( file->read(buf,sizeof(buf)) ){
        qInfo("read: %s",buf);
    }
//  QByteArray ba = file->readAll();
//  qInfo("Data: %s", ba.data());
}
```

Then I run this, the last out put is `cnt: 0`. It seems, that the `read` or `readAll` call now blocks. If I comment out the read calls the counter runs very fast. [here a similiar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989477/qsocketnotifier-and-qfilereadall) That is wrong here?

---

### final solution

Thanks to rodrigo!

*joystick.h*

```
#ifndef JOYSTICK_H
#define JOYSTICK_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QFile>
#include <QSocketNotifier>

class Joystick
      : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QString fileName = "/dev/input/js0";
    QSocketNotifier *notifier;
    int fd;

public:
    explicit Joystick(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~Joystick();

signals:
    void buttonPressed(quint8 number, qint16 value);
    void axisMoved(quint8 number, qint16 value);


public slots:
    void handle_readNotification(int socket);
};

#endif // JOYSTICK_H
```

*joystick.cpp*

```
#include "joystick.h"

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/joystick.h>

Joystick::Joystick(QObject *parent)
   : QObject(parent)
{
    auto file = new QFile();
    file->setFileName(fileName);
    if( !file->exists() ){
        qWarning("file does not exist");
        return;
    }

    fd = open(fileName.toUtf8().data(), O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK);
    if( fd==-1 ){
        qWarning("can not open file");
        return;
    }

    notifier = new QSocketNotifier( fd,
                                    QSocketNotifier::Read,
                                    this);

    connect( notifier,
             &QSocketNotifier::activated,
             this,
             &Joystick::handle_readNotification );
}

Joystick::~Joystick()
{
    if( fd>=0 ){
        close(fd);
    }
}

void
Joystick::handle_readNotification(int /*socket*/)
{
    struct js_event buf;
    while( read(fd,&buf,sizeof(buf))>0 ){
        switch (buf.type) {
        case JS_EVENT_BUTTON:
            emit buttonPressed(buf.number, buf.value);
            break;
        case JS_EVENT_AXIS:
            emit axisMoved(buf.number, buf.value);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a [mcve] of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is usually solved with a polling source for your toolkit. In case of Qt, this is the [`QSocketNotifier`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsocketnotifier.html#details). Despite its name (an historical accident?), it can be used to poll on any file descriptor, not just sockets.

So you just open the device, with `open()` to get the file descriptor, and then create a `QSocketNotifier` on it, with type `QSocketNotifier::Read`. When there are events to be read you will get the `activate()` signal on it.

Comment: `QSocketNotifier` notifies that there are readable content even on empty files. I'm not really sure what `QSocketNotifier` really uses to emit the `activate()` ...

Comment: @Alex44: The `activate()` event is generated internally by using `poll()` or `select()`. What that means is that you can call `read()` on your file descriptor without blocking. Now, reading from an empty file will not block, you'll just get 0 bytes. But reading from a device such a a joystick... will block if there are no pending events. If you read the `js0` only when getting the `activate()` all will work fine.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that is what I do... Then I call `bytesAvailable()` within the `handle_` it returns zero even then there is some input. But why? And it blocks on all files...

Comment: @Alex44: The usual solution is to set the handle of the device as non-blocking, so when reading, instead of blocking when no data is available you will get EAGAIN. Then, in the `activate()` you read the device in a loop until you get EAGAIN, but you will never block. It is possible to do it without blocking and without setting the device as non-blocking, but it is tricky. This way is much easier and more reliable.

Comment: There is no option to set the file handle non-blocking... Did you use standard Unix functions to handle the files?

This post (http://www.archivum.info/qt-interest@trolltech.com/2007-07/00633/Using-Qt-I-O-(QFile)-for-reading-from-files-and-stdin-in-various-modes.html) may describes my problem: _The reason
behind this is that Qt tries to fill its internal buffer with 16K of
data. If there is less data available, it will block until 16K of data
arrive. If it does not happen, then it blocks forever._ And sadly there seems no solution available.

Comment: @Alex44: Do not use `QFile` for devices. Just call `open()` to get a raw FD, set it to non-blocking with `fcntl()` if desired, and use that. No black magic this way. Ah, and do not forget to `close()` it when finish.

Comment: Ok I will do so - the old school way :D. Trying a more modern way based on Qt instead of C.. OK not this time. And yes - `close` - I removed this from the sources because of the comments. THANKS for your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution, if you still want to use QFile instead of low-level read/write functions:

```
auto file = new QFile(fileName);

...

// IMPORTANT: You must set the Unbuffered flag below
if(!file->open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Unbuffered))
{
    // handle error
}

auto fd = file.handle();

auto flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0);
if(flags == -1)
{
    // handle error
}

flags = fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
if(flags == -1)
{
    // handle error
}

auto notifier = new QSocketNotifier(fd, QSocketNotifier::Read, this);

...

struct js_event buf;
while(file->read(&buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0)
{
    // process data
}
```